# Redirecting from one domain to another with mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I've set up a site for someone that has a URL like:
                        `www.flowers-oakville.com`.
But they'd also like `www.flowersoakville.com` to land on the page.

The question now is, what is the best way to redirect from www.flowesoakville.com to www.flowers-oakville.com.  I don't want the user's browser to show the redirection by showing the new URL in the address bar so I think Apache's Redirect command is not the solution. Plus, the Apache Redirect would take an extra trip to the browser and back that I'd like to avoid.   So I think the solution needs to be a mod_rewrite, which as I understand it, does everything within the server so the round trip is avoided and the user's address bar is unchanged.

But after reading through a few mod_rewrite tutorials, it seems that mod_rewrite is mainly for redirecting files, not an entire website. Is there a simple way to  do this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this at the domain level and ensure you are using relative links or an environment variable for the hostname in the website.

Add **www.flowersoakville.com** as a **CNAME** record pointing to **www.flowers-oakville.com**.

This will then serve the same website, but retain the domain name as the user entered it, unless you have explicitly linked the actual domain in a link somewhere in the site.

Comment: Thanks.  Let me make sure I'm following you.  The domain and all the site files is on my server now as flowers-oakville.com. And the domain already has a CNAME record called www.flowers-oakville.com whose value is flowers-oakville.com. Now, you're saying to add another CNAME record called flowersoakville.com whose value is flowers-oakville.com - right? And I suppose I should also create a CNAME record of www.flowersoakville.com and give it the value of flowers-oakville.com.  right?  But could you explain more  what you mean by "using relative links for the hostname in the website"?   Thanks.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  

As to relative links, I mean if you have a link to the about page index for example, it's written as "about/index.htm" and not "http://www.flowers-oakville.com/about/index.htm". That way, whatever domain the user has come to, it will remain that way.

Comment: Had trouble implementing your answer.  See my answer below.  Not your fault.  I'm sure it works for other DNS managers.

Answer (score 0):

If [mode_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)
 is enabled on your server, you can use mod_rewrite (the following code) in your .htaccess file to redirect  a domain to another domain without changing url in the address bar.

Try adding this to `www.flowersoakville.com/.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?flowersoakville\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.flowers-oakville.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,P]
```

Note : The example above will not work if proxy module is not enabled on your server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'd like so share the bounty between the two answers but I don't think that's possible.  I gave it to Dwev because the domain solution does seem simpler.  But I copied your answer into my mod_rewrite notes for future use.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to pass on my experience trying to use Dwev's answer.  It turns out that the DNS Manager running in my virtual server (I'm using eApps as my hosting provider) does not support "domain based redirection." That is, the left side of a CNAME record has to be in that domain. So when trying to build a CNAME record in the flowers-oakville.com record that points to flowers-oakville.com, the left side has to be xxx.flowers-oakville.com where the xxx might be something like www. I can't get the left side to be flowersoakville.com, even though flowersoakville.com is one of the domains my server is listening for.

Comment: That seems pretty strange.  Although I'm not sure I understand fully.  You should add a CNAME record in the flowers-oakville.com pointing to flowersoakville.com or vice versa.  The left side is usually what you want to alias and the right side is what you are resolving to.  On a higher level  you can also use a different DNS to manage your domains, like Amazon's Route 53 for example.

Comment: When you go to create the new CNAME record in flowers-oakville.com the form that comes up has Name:_______.flowers-oakville.com where you could put something like www in the blank field to alias www.flowers-oakville.com to flowers-oakville.com but there's no way to get just flowersoakville.com on the left side.  I think I'll try doing it with mod_rewrite before switching DNS managers. - Thanks